# Exception ao fazer consulta usando DTO em EF .core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Obtenho o seguinte erro ao executar a consulta:

> `"Cannot create a DbSet for 'Cliente_dto' because this type is not included in the model for the context."`

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> CommandSql (string commandSql) 
{
    return dataBase.Set<TEntity>().FromSql(commandSql);                    
}
```

Comment: `Cliente_dto` não é classe configurada para tal operação, então, qual é a classe que determina `Cliente` (acredito ser essa)?

Comment: Sim, tenho a classe cliente.
Mas com a classe Cliente_dto precisava retornar dados que não estão presentes na classe de cliente.

Comment: Não tem muita lógica isso, você precisa criar um exemplo minimo para gente saber bem o que precisa só esse código não diz nada...

Comment: Por exemplo, fazer um Join com outra tabela e retornar dados de abas as tabelas.

Comment: `dataBase.Set<TEntity>().FromSql(commandSql); ` quando você faz assim com `Set<>` você está pedindo ao código aquele tipo, como o tipo não existe se não pode utiliza-lo ai ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Não tem como retornar um DbSet de uma classe dto. Você tem que buscar as informações nas classes entity e depois você popula a classe dto com essas informações.

O que vc pode fazer também é usar Link que você faz a consulta e cria o objeto.

Ex.:

```
   var dto = from cliente in clientes 
     join endereco in enderecos on cliente.id equals endereco.idCliente
     select new ClienteDto (){ Nome = cliente.nome , Rua = endereco.rua };
```